# Parallel populating from SqlDataAdapter to DataSet is it possible?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have this simple code:

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeOut;
            cmd.CommandType = isStoredProcedure ? CommandType.StoredProcedure : CommandType.Text;

            if (parameters != null) //there are parameters to this query
            {
                foreach (string key in parameters.Keys)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(key, parameters[key]);
            }

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
        }

        return ds;
```

Is it possible to do it parallel?

Comment: Whats the nature of parallelism you are looking for? What do you expect a supposed parallel version of `da.Fill(ds)` to do?